# What are the zsh arrays '*' and @ for?

Tags: zsh

If I run `set -A` in zsh to view all arrays, the first two are:

```
awesomeprompt% set -A
'*'=(  )
@=(  )
```

What are the `'*'` and `@` arrays for?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on the [zshparam](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshparam) page:

> The parameters *, @ and argv are arrays containing all the positional parameters; thus '$argv[n]', etc., is equivalent to simply '$n'.

So you can do:

```
awesomeprompt% function testme() { echo $*[1] }
awesomeprompt% testme a
a
awesomeprompt% function testme() { echo $@[1] }
awesomeprompt% testme a
a
```

Comment: I guess in hindsight they are more recognizable with the dollar sign: `$@`, `$*`.